# Adding or replacing a Column based on values of a current Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to add a new column and base its value from another column of a dataframe, on the following 2 conditions, which will not change and will be written to a file after.

1. If number -> (##) (4 character string)
2. If NaN ->         (4 character string of white space)

This is my dataframe.  The column I am interested in is "Code" and that is of type float64.

Current Data Frame Format

```
|    | Num | T(h) | T(m) |   T(s)  | Code |
|:--:|:---:|:----:|:----:|:-------:|:----:|
|  0 |   1 |   10 |  15  | 47.1234 |  NaN |
|  1 |   2 |   10 |  15  | 48.1238 |  1.0 |
|  2 |   3 |   10 |  15  | 48.1364 |  NaN |
|  3 |   4 |   10 |  15  | 49.0101 |  2.0 |
```

Desired Data Frame Format

```
|    | Num | T(h) | T(m) |   T(s)  | Term Code |
|:--:|:---:|:----:|:----:|:-------:|:---------:|
|  0 |   1 |   10 |  15  | 47.1234 |           |
|  1 |   2 |   10 |  15  | 48.1238 |      ( 1) |
|  2 |   3 |   10 |  15  | 48.1364 |           |
|  3 |   4 |   10 |  15  | 49.0101 |      ( 2) |
```

The function I wrote:

```
def insertSoftbrace(tCode):
  value = []
  for item in tCode:
    if str(tCode) == 'NaN': #Blank Line 4 characters
      newCode = '    '
      value.append(newCode)
    else:
      fnum = tCode.astype(float)
      num = fnum.astype(int) #I also tried:  num = int(fnum)
      numStr = str(num)
      newCode = '(' + numStr.rjust(2) + ')'
      value.append(newCode)

  return value

#Changing the float64 to string object, so can use ( )
df['Code'] = df['Code'].astype(str)

#Inserting new column
df.insert(4, "Term Code", insertSoftbrace(df["Code"]))

#I receive the error on: num = fnum.astype(int)
#  "IncastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to intefer. (10 tracebacks)

#When I replace "num = fnum.astype(int)" with " num = int(fnum)"
#  "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> (3 tracebacks)
```

I also attempted this the following way, keeping the Code column as a float64

```
def insertSoft(tCode):
  value = []
  for item in tCode:
    if tCode > 0:           #Format (##)
      num = int(tCode)
      newCode = '(' + numStr.rjust(2) + ')' 
      value.append(newCode)
    else:                   #Format (4) Spaces
      newCode = '    '
      value.append(newCode)

  return value

df.insert(4, "Term Code", insertSoft(df["Code"]))

#Error is given
# ValueError: The truth value of a series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What am I missing with the functions? And how can I produce the desired format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this solution, first use `convert_dtypes` which converts `float` into `int`. Then change to `str`. This is just to remove the decimal point. Change `<NA>` to 4 white spaces. The last step, if the the string isnumeric, use left padding which will ensure the string has length of 2 with white space as filling and add the parenthesis on both sides.

```
df['term_code'] = df['code'].convert_dtypes().astype(str)    
df.loc[df['termcode'] == '<NA>', 'termcode'] = 4 * ' '
df.loc[df['termcode'].str.isnumeric(), 'termcode'] = '(' + df['data'].str.pad(2, 'left') + ')'
```